# Add an html icon class to autogenerated htmlTableCell in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, icons

I have a list that is autogenerated from SQL Server (when add a user) I have an icon that I want it to be also automatically added in the list, with the other cells whenever a row is added.

This is the html of the icon

```
<i class='material-icons'>&#xE5D4;</i>
```

Code:

```
protected void GetUser()
{
    Request REQ = new Request();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = REQ.GetUser();

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow rowM in dt.Rows)
        {
            HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();

            // Create a cell for each column in the row
            HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell1.InnerText = rowM["MAT_USER"].ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cell1);

            // Create a cell for each column in the row
            HtmlTableCell cell2 = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell2.InnerText = rowM["NOM_USER"].ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cell2);

            // Create a cell for each column in the row
            HtmlTableCell cell3 = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell3.InnerText = rowM["PREN_USER"].ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cell3);

            // Create a cell for each column in the row
            HtmlTableCell cell4 = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell4.InnerText = rowM["MAIL_USER"].ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cell4);

            // Create a cell for each column in the row
            HtmlTableCell cell5 = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell5.InnerText = rowM["TEL_USER"].ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cell5);

            // Create a cell for each column in the row
            HtmlTableCell cell6 = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell6.InnerText = rowM["TYPE_USER"].ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cell6);

            Users.Rows.Add(row);   
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this

```
// Create a cell for each column in the row
HtmlTableCell cell7 = new HtmlTableCell();
cell7.InnerHtml = " <asp:Button ID='LBLogout' runat='server' Onclientclick='View_user'><i class='material-icons'>&#xE5D4;</i></asp:Button>";
```

It shows the icon, but it's not clickable because I want to show details (function `View_user`) of every user in the same clicked button row

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: @AVTUNEY i tested it with a message Box but i didn't work                               `public void View_user(object sender, EventArgs e,String userId)
          {
            MessageBox.Show(userId);`}

Answer (score 0):

Add unique identifier to each button and pass it as a parameter to the `View_user` Method.

```
        HtmlTableCell cell7 = new HtmlTableCell();

        var userId = rowM["USER_ID"].ToString();
        cell7.InnerHtml = "<button onclick='View_user(\"" + userId + "\")'><i class='material-icons'>&#xE5D4;</i></button>";
        row.Cells.Add(cell7);
```